# T4 editing the generated code as its generated

Tags: c#, special-characters, code-generation, t4

I have a c# application which generates embedded C code using T4 templates. 
However I have a small problem with the resulting output which I wonder if there is an elegant solution.

The issue is I loop around both for loops and foreach to create enums and other tables using the following T4 template:

```
typedef enum eSDef_Index
{
<#    for (int i = 0; i < ScreenDefinitions.Count(); i++)
      { #>
    SD_IDX_<#=ScreenDefinitions[i].Name.ToUpper() #> = <#=i#>,
<#    }
      // >>>> Can we do a backspace here?
#>
}eSDEF_INDEX;
```

This successfully creates the enum i want. However the C compiler I am using does not like the last enum entry to have the comma. I could fix this by checking if this is the last item in the list, however i wonder if there is a more elgant way?

My idea was to effectively delete the last comma after it has been generate using a backspace maybe.

So is it possible to add special characters which directly affect the generated code? or any other way of doing this?

Comment: I found a bit more information which is that you can use PushIndex("\t") to insert a tab. Therefore one would assume(?) that you can do PushIndex("\b") to do a backspace, however at actually puts a charater holder there instead so does not do as I would expect :(

Comment: What compiler are you using (that is not conformant).

Comment: @Luca its a very old ST Cosmic compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's impossible.

Why not use `string.Join` method?

```
typedef enum eSDef_Index
{
    <#= string.Join(",\r\n    ",
            ScreenDefinitions.Select((x, i) =>
                $"SD_IDX_{x.Name.ToUpper()} = {i}")
    ) #>
}eSDEF_INDEX;
```

---

Place comment into first parameter (separator):

```
    <#= string.Join(", // Comment \r\n    ",
            ScreenDefinitions.Select((x, i) =>
                "SD_IDX_" + x.Name.ToUpper() + " = " + i)
    ) #>
```

Comment: Many thanks, i've never used the Join or Select methods before. I did have to make a change to get it to generate correctly: `"SD_IDX_" + x.Name.ToUpper() + " = " + i)`. Maybe edit your post with this correction for others. Thanks.

Comment: I also have an enum which has comments after each enum, used for reference. This means the comma is in the middle of the string. How could I manage this? So using my first post example: `SD_IDX_<#=ScreenDefinitions[i].Name.ToUpper() #> = <#=i#>, // Comment`

Comment: @TheGrovesy - See update. `$"..."` - is interpolated string appeared in C#6.